# How to get db2 query output in the following form?

Tags: xml, db2, db2-luw

I have a DB2 LUW database, I need the query output in the following form. Each row in from the query output should be in a single line as follows. Thanks in advance for youe help.

Example:-

Table - employee

columns :- First_name,Last_name,Department

Output:-

```
<First_name>Adam</First_name><Last_name>Santner</Last_name></dept>hr</dept>
<First_name>John</First_name><Last_name>Milne</Last_name><dept>hr</dept>
<First_name>Mike</First_name><Last_name>Tyson</Last_name><dept>hr</dept>
```

and so on

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Include what you tried so far and why you are not succeeding. You probably have tried XMLROW or other functions, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
You may uncomment the commented out lines to run this statement as is and get the result as you specified.
Refer to the [XMLROW scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-xmlrow) description.

```
/*
WITH EMPLOYEE (First_name, Last_name, dept) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('Adam', 'Santner', 'hr')
, ('John', 'Milne',   'hr')
, ('Mike', 'Tyson',   'hr')
)
*/
SELECT SUBSTRING (S, 6, CHARACTER_LENGTH (S) - 11) AS S 
FROM 
(
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE (XMLROW (First_name AS "First_name", Last_name AS "Last_name", dept AS "dept") AS VARCHAR (1000)) AS S
FROM EMPLOYEE
) T
```